# CGLFlushDrawable in OpenGL not waiting for monitor refresh on OS X 10.13 and 10.14

Tags: macos

I'm using DoubleBuffering and have swap interval set to 1, so flushBuffers should block openGL code until the swap is completed.

I therefore have this setup on a separate thread:

```
for(i=0 i< numFrames i++) {

// some drawing stuff


[[NSOpenGLContext currentContext] flushBuffer];

glFinish();

// get the time

}
```

In prior versions of OS X (and with different hardware), this works fine: the vast majority of the time I have time intervals corresponding to one frame, and occasionally I have two.

But now (on new hardware and 10.13 and 10.14), this fails. I have a huge number of very low intervals (sub ms), and some large intervals, but no obviously clustering of intervals around integer numbers of frames.

BTW, I'm doing this because it's critical that frames are delivered in a regular, dependable manner, and, if they aren't, I want to know about it.

I'm really at a loss, and am thinking the only possibility is that something has changed with OS X and the opengl drivers, but Apple makes it hard to go backwards OS version-wise, so I thought I'd get some advice before I go down that road.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code for how you set the swap interval? Can you try a test to see if it works more correctly on the main thread than background threads? As a stab in the dark, does adding `[CATransaction flush];` after `glFinish()` help?

Comment: GLint swapParam = 1;
[openGLContext setValues:&swapParam forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval]; and I'm not using Core Animation

Comment: The framework may be using Core Animation behind your back. Especially for 10.14, the view hierarchy is layer-backed regardless. That's why I suggested that.

Comment: OK. Gave it a try and still no change: a lot of intervals less than 0.2 ms.

Comment: I'm don't this think is an OS issue, but rather an AMD or eGPU driver issue. On my MacBook Pro things behave properly when I use the onboard Intel graphics chip, but when I hook up the eGPU, they don't.